# How to get a booking confirmation to Gmail in Google Calendar

Tags: email, gmail, google-calendar

I'm owner of a day-spa and I've read on several places that a reservation email (like hotel booking) send to Gmail can show up automatic in Google Calendar.

Do you need to do something special with these reservation emails? 
Like to put in a code or something?

Answer (score 2):

The markup you're looking for is [schema data](http://schema.org/Reservation) that needs to be embedded in the email HTML.

You can find details of it in Gmail's reference docs: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/hotel-reservation

Gmail will then scan the e-mail and in most cases automatically generate the associated features for a user.